# Ask in C++ code to promp user for function expression input

Tags: c++, function, input

C++ code to prompt user for function expression input.

I try to make a code where after the RUN the interface to ask me to write the expression of function like pow(x,2)+5 and the program to read it and understand it with its mathematical expression.

So, instead to declare from the beginning:

```
double f(double x) {   pow(x,2)+5;
}
```

I want something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,i;        //n is for subintervals and i is for loop
    double a,b,h,sum=0,integral;  
    double f(double x)  
    cout<<"Enter the expression of the function f(x)=";  // I will answer writing "pow(x,2)+5"
    cin>>f;
```

How I can do that ?

---

Comment: C++ is a compiled language, so code is translated into machine instructions and stored in an executable file which can then be executed. Therefore, you cannot execute code inputted by the user. You must parse the expression yourself and write code that evaluates it.

Comment: There is no easy way to do that in C++. You would have to write a parser and model the function as a tree of expressions where each expression is a custom object.

Comment: There is already a program call bc, short for bench calculator that does this. Have a look at its source and fork it if necessary.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bc-command-linux-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can split **expression** from user via standard input like `string`. User write `string` and your code parse it. For **parser** you can use ***Shunting-yard algorithm***: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

And you can check this github page (**The Parsing Expression Grammar Template Library**): https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL